# How to Load a URDF File to RVIZ

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a URDF file of my own robot, but I don't know how to load it to RVIZ.
I've googled but still don't get it.

I'm very new to ROS. Any help will be appreciated.

If there is a step-by-step tutorial, that will be even better.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297615/how-to-load-a-urdf-file-to-rviz/) by [huang27c](https://answers.ros.org/users/36402/huang27c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-07-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Check out this launch file](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/blob/master/launch/display.launch)

You're in luck if you want a step by step tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials#Learning_URDF_Step_by_Step

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [huang27c](https://answers.ros.org/users/36402/huang27c/) on 2018-07-16**:
Hi David! Do I create a package and put URDF in src? Where do I place the launch file?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-07-16**:
Yes, both could go in a package called robotname_description.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-16**:
@David Lu looks like you beat me to it :)

**Comment by [huang27c](https://answers.ros.org/users/36402/huang27c/) on 2018-07-16**:
Thank you so much!